# what are necessary conditions for $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \to \mathbb{E}[X]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables. What type of convergence to $X$ (or additional conditions) is required to ensure convergence of the means?

I think convergence in probability is not enough in general. However, convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution (or law) and that implies that for any $g$ bounded and continuous:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] = \mathbb{E}[g(X)]. $$
So, in particular, if $X_n$ and $X$ can only take a finite set of values, taking $g$ to be the identity, the convergence would follow. Is that true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you wrote about g having a finite set of values is correct. also if you're interested in the convergence in probability thing - if you additionally assume that the family $X_n$ is uniformly integrable then what you wrote will be true
actually you'll even get something better, you'll get $L_1$ convergence, ie $E |X_n - X|$ will converge to 0 - it's a well known theorem

Comment: Thanks! What if $X_n$ and $X$ take values in a bounded interval $(a,b)$, convergence in law is again enough for convergence of the means?

Comment: yeah, if you want to make this 'rigorous' just take a continuous function f defined as follows $f(x) = x$ for $x \in (a, b)$, $f(x) = a$ for $x < a$ and similarly $f(x) = b$ for $x > b$ it's continuous and bounded, so everything works out fine. oh, and also a uniformly bounded family is always uniformly integrable